# Suitable project for reinforcement learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, games

To get more insight in reinforcement learning I'm looking for a project for. I thought about the game connect four.

Doing some research about existing works with RL and connect four I found out that there are plenty other ways to teach a computer this game. That was to be expected. 
So the question arises as to whether RL might be a bad idea or even an overkill. If similar or better results can be achieved in an hour with simpler/ more common approaches like decision trees or MLP, I'd rather not continue with this project.

If I could at least beat simpler approaches, I think I'd try. 
Another question is how much work this task requires. Of course this depends strongly on the knowledge of RL. I have basic knowledge of general Machine Learning and common Deep Learning approaches. Are we speaking about hours, days weeks or even months to set up such a model and train it?

Comment: The best person to ask about suitably of a particular project would be your instructor.

Comment: @Sycorax and as good student I do some research before and don't relay on a single persons opinion. There are people out there which know much more about RL since its one very unique branch of Machine Learning.

Comment: Tic tac toe: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Tic-Tac-Toe+Endgame

Comment: @Aksakal thank you for the data set. there is even one for connect four. however this does not really contribute to the RL task or my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RL is a very broad field, and the appropriate "test"-game depends on what exactly you're interested in.

> If similar or better results can be achieved in an hour with simpler/ more common approaches like decision trees or MLP, I'd rather not continue with this project.

I suggest you start off with a simple game/task, and once you are confident in your ability to solve that task, then move on to a more challenging one. To do something with RL which no other algorithm/approach can accomplish requires a lot of prior expertise and familiarity with the game and algorithm, so it's not a good way to learn anything.

For each area of RL, I've listed an easy environment on which it'd be appropriate to play around, and then a much more challenging environment.

**Continuous control**: Inverted pendulum control is a good starter test project. Robotic manipulation from *visual inputs* is a much more challenging problem (see Fetch environments in OpenAI Gym).

**Discrete control**: Pong is a simple game to start with. Many harder Atari games are also frequently used, including the infamous "Montezuma's Revenge".

**Multi-Agent games**: OpenAI's [multi-agent particle environments](https://github.com/openai/multiagent-particle-envs) provide a set of neat test-cases for both cooperative and competitive settings. For more of a challenge, try out Go.

Comment: Wow thanks four your answer. Really appreciate it! Guess it would be a good idea to make my project scalable by adding more difficult games to play. From your answer I assume you're saying that connect four should be possible after some experiments? Compared to Go it has to be peanuts.

Comment: @Mr.Sh4nnon yes, it is good practice when writing RL code (and code in general!) to make the code sufficiently general that it is fairly painless to swap out one game for another during development. Connect 4 sounds good.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the OpenAI Gym. It gives you different applications, environments and projects to build, as well as a nice [Getting Started](https://gym.openai.com/docs/) document. You can also submit your results to the leader board to compare the performance of your model to others.

[OpenAI Gym](https://gym.openai.com/)

Comment: Cool idea thanks! But would you say RL is suitable to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, it is an excellent platform designed for individuals to test RL algorithms and compare the performance.